# Deedle - comma decimal delimeter in CSV

Tags: c#, .net, csv, deedle

Trying to load CSV file with deedle (`Frame.ReadCsv`), but I have comma as decimal delimeter in float fields, so they are readed as ints (ignoring commas).

Is there any way to load it?

Comment: How would a program tell which commas are field delimiters and which commas are decimal delimiters?

Comment: to put it simply: your CSV is malformed. probably it was generated with home-brewed code instead of using one of the many, many, many existing libraries to generate CSV. your best bet would be to ***fix*** the code generating the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a CSV file that uses comma for both decimal numbers and as a separator, then there is no way to parse that, because it is ambiguous. For example:

```
One,Two
1,2,3
```

Should this be parsed as `1,2` and `3`, or should it be parsed as `1` and `2,3`? If you want to use comma for decimal numbers, you'll need to use something else as a separator. For example, a semicolon `;`

```
One; Two
1,2; 3
```

This is now unambiguous and you can parse it. You need to specify your `separators`. As a bonus, you can also specify a culture which uses `,` as a decimal number separator to get your decimal numbers parsed correctly. This is the case in the Czech culture, for example, so the following parses the file as expected:

```
Frame.ReadCsv("c:/temp/test.csv", separators:";", culture:"cs-CZ")
```